# Look up data by string and range number as keys

Tags: c++, data-structures, range, lookup

I am looking for a data structure in C++ or implement one to have different tables with a list of strings as name and each table uses number ranges as keys.

The main operation where the most of performance is required would be two lookup operations:

1. Get table by the name in the list.
2. In each table, get the string value by a number in the specific range.

For example, assuming the following map

```
Table1 name = ["One", "Two"]
    [ 5, 20] -> "Apple"
    [25, 50] -> "Boat"
    [60, 100] -> "Cow"

Table2 name = ["Three"]
    [ 5, 20] -> "Air"
    [25, 50] -> "Bard"
    [60, 100] -> "Camera"
```

when given operation like `query("Two", 15)`:

```
"Two" -> Table1
15 -> "Apple"
```

Are there any made solutions? any comments are appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen those kind of c++ functions. is that a new update ? or is that just a pseudocode? please clarify

Comment: S@ShreeyashShrestha: pseudocode, since the author had no idea how to express it in C++. As the first answer shows, you need an external library such as Boost to represent intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a hashmap e.g., [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [`absl::flat_hash_map`](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/container/flat_hash_map.h), with an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), e.g., [`boost::icl::interval_map`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/icl/interval_map.hpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>

using boost::icl::interval;
using Table = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::string>;
using Database = std::unordered_map<std::string, Table>;

std::string Query(Database& db, const std::string& table_name, int number) {
  auto table_it = db.find(table_name);
  if (table_it != db.end()) {
    auto& table = table_it->second;
    auto range_it = table.find(number);
    if (range_it != table.end()) {
      return range_it->second;
    }
  }
  return "Not Found";
}

int main() {
  Database db;
  db["One"].insert(std::make_pair(interval<int>::closed(5, 20), "Apple"));
  db["One"].insert(std::make_pair(interval<int>::closed(25, 50), "Boat"));
  db["One"].insert(std::make_pair(interval<int>::closed(60, 100), "Cow"));
  db["Two"] = db["One"];
  db["Three"].insert(std::make_pair(interval<int>::closed(5, 20), "Air"));
  db["Three"].insert(std::make_pair(interval<int>::closed(25, 50), "Bard"));
  db["Three"].insert(std::make_pair(interval<int>::closed(60, 100), "Camera"));
  std::cout << "Query(Two, 15): " << Query(db, "Two", 15) << '\n';
  std::cout << "Query(Three, 30): " << Query(db, "Three", 30) << '\n';
  std::cout << "Query(One, 65): " << Query(db, "One", 65) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```bash
Query(Two, 15): Apple
Query(Three, 30): Bard
Query(One, 65): Cow
```

Comment: Thanks, may I know the time complexity of insert/find of interval_map? how does it be implemented generally?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree (added link in the answer as well) Also if you click on boost::icl::interval_map you can see the source code FYI.